# Number of spanning trees of a labeled graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

This labeled graph is given, I need to find the number of its spanning trees.

[image]

The number of spanning trees of the following graph is 3

[image]

and the number of spanning trees of this is 8

[image]

So as a result the number of spanning trees of the graph is $3^2 \times 8^3 = 4608$ while it is not the correct answer.

Comment: you should ask for a refund.

Comment: where is the question from? could I see a link ?

Comment: How do you know your solution is incorrect?

Comment: @AustinMohr It was a Ph.D entrance exam question and $4608$  was not among the choices

Comment: what are the choices?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream they are $1394 - 1944 - 4900 - 9000$

Comment: Well, I agree with you completely.

Comment: What difference does it make when the graph is labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: The labels look like they take away some of the symmetries you would otherwise have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning looks correct. And, according to Sage, 4608 is indeed the number of spanning trees.

[image]

Comment: the Sage calculates the labeled graph or unlabeled?

Comment: It gives you labelled. If you want unlabelled the answer will be less.If you want unlabelled the answer is less than 1000. So the results is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks, sounds they made a mistake and it took 8 minutes of my time